# CSS Animation Stop on last part and remain to its default style

Tags: html, css

How to stop the animation and keep the text when it comes to the 100% in keyframes, because it disappear when it reach 100%, well I did try infinite but it seems it wasn't fit for my taste, what I want is only two or more then display remain to its default style.

```css
 p span {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #ec1839;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: titleAnimation;
    animation-timing-function:ease;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-50px);
      opacity: 0;
      clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  }
  20% {
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
      clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  80% {
       transform: translateY(0);
       opacity: 1;
       clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  90% {
       transform: translateY(50px);
       opacity: 0;
       clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% -0%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p><span>< Hi >, Nice to see you here</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

### The animation ends at 100%

Set 100% to desired end state for the animation

```css
p span {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #ec1839;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: titleAnimation;
    animation-timing-function:ease;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { // Starting condition
      transform: translateY(-50px);
      opacity: 0;
      clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  }
  20% {
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
      clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  100% {  // This where the animation will end and stay at
       transform: translateY(0);
       opacity: 1;
       clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p><span>< Hi >, Nice to see you here</span></p>
```